# How to determine the number of "Column Name" in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `tblEmployeeInfo`which has atleast a 100+ `column name`.
I want to know how many `column name` are in that table. Is that possible?

NOTE:
`tbleEmployeeInfo` has no data inside yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP didn't show any effort... There's no code in question and a quick Google search yields many results.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views.  You can see all the columns and their types by doing:

```
select c.*
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
where table_name = 'tbleEmployeeInfo';
```

(You might want to include the `table_schema` as well.)

To get the count, just use `COUNT(*)`:

```
select count(*)
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
where table_name = 'tbleEmployeeInfo';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   sys.columns
WHERE  object_id = object_id('tblEmployeeInfo')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: It's not obvious to me whether this is better than Gordon Linoff's answer using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` (which looks portable to other SQL implementations; I don't think that `sys` is portable).

Comment: We posted the answer about the same time.